# changing text colour in kable, in Rmarkdown, in latex with % label leads to unwanted "\" proceeding % label when knit

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I'm trying to knit a table in a large Rmarkdown document. The table represent disease levels on a farm and thus some are expressed as percentages percentages. When the disease levels are above target I would like to highlight by changing the color of the font to red. This works fine when text does not have a % label, but when I escape the % label the % label in the PDF document is always proceeded by an unwanted "". I'm a vet not a data scientist I have spent many hours on this but can't find an answer.

The original document is extremely complex pulling data from many sources to generate the current disease levels and targets using shiny input to determine various options so not possible to use code from the original document. But I have produced a very minimal reproducible example below

```r
require(kableExtra)
require(scales)
library(knitr)
require(tidyverse)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
MDF = data.frame(a = label_percent()(.07),b = label_percent()(.05))
MDF$a = as.character(MDF$a)
MDF$b = as.character(MDF$b)
MDF[1,] = apply(MDF[1,],2,function(f) gsub("%", "\\\\%", f))
MDF = MDF %>% mutate(a = cell_spec(a, color = ifelse(a > 6,"red","black")))
kable(MDF, "latex", escape = F, booktabs = T)
```

Comment: Could you please provide your current and expected results?

Comment: Sorry Marcelo realised I hadn't done that after posting. Stephan below answered perfectly. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I get it the issue is that the percent sign in the conditionally formatted cell gets escaped twice, once via the `gsub` and once via `kable` itself so that you end up with an additional `\textbackslash()` inserted in you latex code. Hence, one option to solve your issue would be to manually escape only the percent signs in the column to which you don't apply the conditional formatting:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
require(kableExtra)
require(scales)
library(knitr)
require(tidyverse)

MDF = data.frame(a = .07, b = .05) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(a, b), percent)) %>% 
  # Escape percent sign in column b only
  mutate(across(c(b), ~ gsub("%", "\\\\%", .x))) %>% 
  mutate(a = cell_spec(a, color = ifelse(a > 6,"red","black")))
  
kable(MDF, "latex", escape = F, booktabs = T)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. Sorry for the late response. I also found escape = F on cell_spec also worked which fits well with your reasoning.